# Где можно найти такой слайдер?

Tags: jquery, slider, javascript, вёрстка, css

Привет.

Где можно найти такой слайдер? То есть сначала это обычный слайдер, а при нажатии на любой слайд, оно появляется во всплывающем блоке, котрый также является слайдером.

[image]

Comment: @Руслан Сабанов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: По рекомендации @Сергей, посмотрите аналогичный вопрос http://hashcode.ru/questions/223622/

Answer (score 2):

Берёте любой плагин слайдера, например, SlidesJs или IdealImageSlider, и прикручиваете к нему плагин галереи, например,  Fancybox или Lightbox. Всё прекрасно работает при правильном использовании.

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то написала для одного из проектов [вот такой слайдер с модальным окном](https://github.com/OlgaMaraeva/responsive-carusel-with-modal).

В разработке скрипта очень помог eicto. Может быть, это решение Вам поможет.

Answer (score 0):

http://dropthebit.com/demos/photobox/ вот